# Find last row of specific range of data excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet that contains these data (attached Picture)
[image]

I want to have the selected row in (Remaining sheet)
The selected row is last data of (35,000IQD) in erbil city.

That means I want to have last row of in (specific) city with specific(card type)
(there is two row of data of erbil city with card type 35,000 I want to give me the last one)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: This is not a free coding service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you try this code:

```
Sub MatchingCityAndCardType1()
Dim City As String, i As Long, Last_Row As Long
Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

For i = Last_Row To 2 Step -1
    City = Cells(i, "C").Value
    If City = "erbil" And Mid(Cells(i, "E"), 1, 6) = "35,000" Then
        MsgBox "The card remaining of " & City & " city with card type " _
        & Cells(i, "E").Value & " is " & Cells(i, "J").Value & "."
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

The output of this code is

[image]

---

As per pashew's request in the comment below, this code should work

```
    Sub MatchingCityAndCardType2()
    Dim City As String, i As Long, Last_Row As Long
    Last_Row = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = Last_Row To 2 Step -1
        City = Cells(i, "C").Value
        If City = "erbil" And Mid(Cells(i, "E"), 1, 6) = "35,000" Then
            'Set the range destination, Range(“A2”), depending on which 
            'range you want in Sheets(“Remaining”)
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Remaining").Range("A2")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    End Sub
```

I put this code in the worksheet code module: **Main Data Sheet**.

Comment: Dear Sir i want to move these value to (remaining sheet) in one row
Date               city       card type         card NO.     free    Card remaining
27/09/2016    erbil       35,000            27               1        3
Thanks for your support

Comment: Dear @Anastasiya-Romanova  i want to move these value to (remaining sheet) in one row

(27/09/2016  /  erbil   /    35,000    /        27       /        1   /     3)
and i want to move the others like (erbil -- 4,8000)(soran --35,000)(soran-- 48,000) 
and so on
(last entered data with filter of city and card type)you can select last entered data by date
in picture there are 3 columns with (erbil-35,000) i want to move the last one 
Thanks for your kind support

Comment: Dear Mr. @pashew, the 2nd code does the job by copying entire row 8 in "Main Data Sheet" to row 2 in "Remaining" sheet. But I don't understand your next request. Can you give me the picture of the data that you want to move instead of explaining using
 words?

Comment: this line don't work givs error
Sheets(“Main Data Sheet”).Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy

Comment: Amazing it's working
Can i make it give me some of these data because i don't need all of theme
and can you make it just give me data not format cells , in the remaining sheet i have different style
thank you again you really helped me thank you

Comment: @pashew In my opinion, you should ask another question for that request but make sure this time state clearly what you want and show your attempt. I'm glad I can be of help

Comment: Dear  @Anastasiya-Romanova 秀 .. thank you for kind support i have what i need ..... thank you again  :)

Comment: Dear @Anastasiya-Romanova 秀 ... what if i add one more condition like (name)? that mean (city , name  and card type)----thank you in advance

Comment: @pashew Add a variable `Name = Cells(i, "D").Value` before the loop and change the condition to for example `If City = "erbil" And Mid(Cells(i, "E"), 1, 6) = "35,000" And Name = "dana" Then`

Comment: Dear @Anastasiya-Romanova 秀 . you really helped me . i have one last question ** :) ** ... what if i want to create another range of sheets based on monthly(create sheet for jan , feb ....and containing the whole data of this month) ? that mean 2 range of sheets the first range based on row(d) and the second range based on date (row c). i asked many people they didn't answer me....** thank you for your Kind support **

Comment: please help i really need it

Comment: @pashew I've just got online. Where is that question? Can you post it & make sure this time you state clearly your request so I can help you

Comment: Dear @Anastasiya-Romanova 秀 . you really helped me . i have one last question ** :) ** ... what if i want to create another range of sheets based on monthly(create sheet for jan , feb ....and containing the whole data of this month) ? that mean 2 range of sheets the first range based on row(d) and the second range based on date (row c). i asked many people they didn't answer me....** thank you for your Kind support **

Comment: @pashew You kept repeating your question but I'm not really sure what are asking for that's why I ask you to post another question regarding your problem so that I can fully understand your request. I'll help you if I really understand your question completely

Comment: Sorry i am confused hhhh. see this link(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499331/extract-to-sheets-by-month) and you understand me :)

Comment: :my question in mentioned page is blocked if you can answer it here it will be greate

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't help. It's out of my coding skills. Maybe you can update your question by adding flowchart of your algorithm so that someone here can help you.

Comment: i am really appreciate your support and  thank you again

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways you could approach this:

- Using the method Anastasiya-Romanova has stated.
- Using an Autofilter and special cells
- Using an Array
- And probably more

This one uses the `find` method which is faster then looping.

I'm assuming the card type is an integer value and not string, but if it is a string just updated the `CardType` as string and wrap the value in quotes.

```
Sub FindLastRow()
    Dim city As String, FirstAddress As String
    Dim CardType As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim a

    city = "erbil"
    CardType = 35000

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Data Sheet")
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 10))
    End With

    With rng
        Set a = .Find(what:=city, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = a.Address
            Do
                If a.Offset(0, 2) = CardType Then
                    ' Update this part with whatever you want to do to the last row
                    MsgBox a.Address
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    Set a = .FindNext(a)
                End If
            Loop While Not a Is Nothing And a.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear @Tom 
i want to move these value to (remaining sheet) in one row (27/09/2016 / erbil / 35,000 / 27 / 1 / 3) and i want to move the others like (erbil -- 4,8000)(soran --35,000)(soran-- 48,000) and so on (last entered data with filter of city and card type)you can select last entered data by date in picture there are 3 columns with (erbil-35,000) i want to move the last one Thanks for your kind support